# Ionic controller XMLHttpRequest function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

does somebody know why this doesn't work? I get a error message at 'request.status' in Ionic

```
    .factory('Nieuws', function() {

  var url = "http://echo.jsontest.com/ID/2/bericht/test";
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url);
  var nieuws;
  request.onload = function () {
    if (request.status = 200) {
      nieuws = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
      //console.log(nieuws);

    }
  };
```

Comment: "a error message" — I don't suppose you care to share that error message with us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign a value to a read only property when you need to be making a comparison.

Replace `=` with `==`.